# Файл favicon.ico есть в корне, но получаю ответ "Not Found"

Tags: node.js

Приложение Koa

```
const favicon = require('koa-favicon');
app.use(favicon());
```

В корневой папке, где находится index.js, есть файл favicon.ico;
В отладчике Chrome я вижу запрос на Localhost (network/favicon.ico) с ответом, что файла нет, хотя он есть:
.
Request URL: http://localhost:3006/favicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
.
Если указать так:

```
app.use(favicon(process.cwd()));
```

либо так:

```
app.use(favicon((process.cwd() + '/favicon.ico'));
```

ничего не поменяется, "Not Found"
.
Как правильно отдавать этот favicon.ico с помощью модуля koa-favicon ?

Comment: `console.log(process.cwd() + '/favicon.ico')` есть на диске? `process.cwd()` - плохой вариант, так как зависит от рабочего каталога. Используйте `__dirname`. И вообще вся статика отдается так: `app.use(express.static('public'));` - чем плох этот вариант?

Comment: console.log(process.cwd() + '/favicon.ico на диске есть. Попробую static... Но для чего тогда "koa-favicon" ?

Comment: static - это для express. Перепутал koa с express. `app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));` [Написано тут](https://github.com/koajs/favicon) - тоже не работает?

Comment: Немного перефразирую вопрос. После запуска сервера, я открываю в Chrome страницу http://localhost:nnnn/ и в меню Network вижу, что автоматически отправляется запрос favicon.ico (Request URL: http://localhost:3009/favicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found. Вопрос, как мне нужно переделать код или куда положить этот файл favicon.ico, чтобы сервер отдавал файл .ico, а не ошибку "Not Found" ? Запрос идет именно в корневой каталог http://localhost:xxxx/favicon.ico

Comment: В favicon.ico нет русских букв?

Comment: покопался глубже..вопрос уже переформатируется )) ответ сервера  "404 Not Found" на автозапрос браузера "favicon.ico" означает не отсутствие файла, а отсутствие обработчика этого запроса. Если у меня есть обработчик страницы "/foo"  (const Router = require('koa-router');

const router = new Router(); router.get('/foo'...) то я получаю от сервера Status Code: 200 OK при загрузке страницы http://localhost:xxx/foo. Получается, ошибка "Not Found" вылазит, если нет обработчика. Но ! Если я делаю обработчик с нормальным (непрерывным) именем, все. ок (Not Found не вылазит, получаю 200)

Comment: Но если я обработчик пишу на этот авто-запрос (favicon.ico), он через точку в имени ("."), то почему-то этот обработчик не виден, и в ответ "Not Found". Поэкспериментировал - обработчики с простыми именами просто из букв получают 200 (localhost:xxx/foo444, localhost:xxx/foo55jj55 и т.д.) но если localhost:xxx/foo.444 (и такой обработчик есть (router.get('/foo.444), то получаю 404...